# How to properly modify text opacity in Angular Material and the overall accessibility of Angular Material typography in general

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material, accessibility

**Problem:** I am getting pushback from my accessibility team about the contrast of Angular Material's disabled text color. When displayed on a white background, the text is apparently too light. I have been given the expected colors to use for regular text and disabled text, which are #272a2b and #6b6d71 respectively.

**Consideration:** I can see that by default, Angular Material's regular text is `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)` and disabled text is `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38)`. To adjust the text alpha/opacity of the text for all components, there would ideally be a way to configure the default opacities. I have gone through the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/guide/typography) for customizing typography, and the ability to adjust these values is not mentioned.

**Solution Attempt 1:** I am able to override specific texts. For example, I can use this CSS rule to make disabled mat-selection-list items appear darker than they would be by default:

```
.mat-mdc-list-item-title {
  color: #272a2b;
  --mdc-list-list-item-disabled-label-text-color: #6b6d71;
  --mdc-list-list-item-disabled-label-text-opacity: 1;
}
```

However, I don't like this method because I will have to override disabled text colors for every single Angular Material component: buttons, form fields, etc. This is also insufficient for components like mat-form-field, which change the color of other nested elements depending on the state of the field: label color, outline color, etc. There must be a better way, right?

**Questions**

1. How can I globally set the opacity of the various text levels throughout the entire application?
2. If I do have to individually override disabled text colors per component, where can I find a list of or documentation for all "double-dash" variables for given Angular Material components e.g. mdc-text-field--disabled?
3. Assuming my accessibility department is correct, and that Angular Material version 15 has a strong focus on accessibility, how can it be that disabled text is still being flagged for poor contrast? Is Angular Material's disabled text color actually compliant with the latest accessibility rules? I've found this section [1.4.3 of WCAG](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#contrast-minimum) that states "Text or images of text that are part of an inactive user interface component [...] have no contrast requirement."

Comment: Your last #3point is correct and is what popped into my head just reading your first paragraph. There is no WCAG contrast requirement for disabled text, assuming "disabled text" means text on an interactive element that can't be clicked on. I mention this because I've seen people say that paragraph text, when it's not applicable in a certain situation, is considered "disabled text", but that's not accurate. "Disabled text" is text associated with an interactive element. That doesn't mean the text should not be readable, but there's a balance between readable and inactive.